# How does amazon streams kinesis shard count calculator formula works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, sharding

I am trying to learn aws kinesis streams ,and as per aws kinesis streams documentation.
 Each shard ingests up to 1MB/sec or 1000 records/sec, and allows reads up to 2MB/sec and 5 transaction per second for reads.

**Therefore my doubt is::**
If my data packet size is 250kb ,and only 1MB write per shard is allowed, then to get a throughput of 200 message per second ,i would be needing approx.50 shards(49 as per aws shard calculator,given in picture below).But while using shard-calculator provided by AWS,it  also asks for the number of consumers, which if I provide,(say 3 consumers),it increases the shard count from  50 to 74,NOw my question is ,how does adding consumers alter the count of shards required?
[image]

So Could someone please  explain the logic here.
Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if you are missing the nuance of the term consumer *applications*.  You have 2 consumer *applications* if you are receiving and processing two complete copies of all the stream shards, independently.  This is not the same as the number *n* of worker nodes you might have, each one handling 1 / *n* of the shards, which as you correctly deduce, does not impact the number of shards needed.  Multiple worker nodes can collectively make up 1 consumer application.

Comment: Thanks Michael ,correct me if i am wrong,since worker is a thread so does KCL automatically forks new thread based the number of shards available. also when you said each worker node handling 1/n of the shard ,does this mean a worker node having iterators working at different indexs of the data in the shard.

Comment: Note the phrasing: [*"You can deploy the consumer to an EC2 instance by adding to one of your AMIs. You can scale the consumer by running it on multiple EC2 instances under an Auto Scaling group."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/amazon-kinesis-consumers.html) The word "consumer" is conspicuously singular here, in spite of discussion of multiple instances.  See also [KCL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/developing-consumers-with-kcl.html) functionality.

Comment: by reading amazon kinesis documentation what i understand is that read and write are independent operations in terms of actions performed on the shard,so by provisioning specific number of shards for writing,we are only addressing our write speed for producers. Also when it comes to reading data fast,it depends firstly upon the number of shards as greater number mean each kcl worker will get its own piece without worrying about time sharing resource. but agin it goes from case to case.

Comment: Where did you find this shard calculator?

Answer (score 4):

AWS has defined the below formula to calculate the number of shards

**Number_of_shards = max(incoming_write_bandwidth_in_KiB/1024, outgoing_read_bandwidth_in_KiB/2048)**

In your case,

**incoming_write_bandwidth_in_KiB** =

```
avg.data size in kb * records per second
                                = 250 * 200 = 50000
```

**outgoing_read_bandwidth_in_KiB**  =

```
incoming_write_bandwidth_in_KiB * consumers
                                =  50000 * 3 = 150000
```

So, No.of.Shards

```
= max (50000/1024,150000/2048)
                 = max (48.8 , 73.2)
                 = 73.2
```

***and hence 74 shards.***

Comment: @sal - Does the above makes sense?

Comment: Thanks @Muzammil, yes it does, its been a while i posted this question ,i now moved to kafka,but thanks for the nice explanation, btw when i posted this question i might have been referring to the consumer group with three consumers. which will cause the payload to be distributed among them ,instead of having three separate datasets copies.

Comment: For those who is interested, link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/how-do-i-size-a-stream.html